# Dimension of a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times 2^n$ binary matrix of all the possible unique binary numbers with length $n$. For example, if $n = 3$, $$A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right) $$
Prove that at most $2^{n-1}$ of the columns of $A$ can belong to a real vector space with dimension $n -1$.

My attempt would to be to prove the contrapositive, namely, if we choose more than $2^{n-1}$ columns of $A$  then the rank of this subset must equal $n$. It seems that if we have more then $2^{n-1}$ columns of $A$ then at least one of the rows will have a different entry for at least one of the columns.

Comment: which field you are working over?

Comment: The real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to consider all the columns for which the last cohordinate is zero. You obtain a $n-1$ dimension space because al the vectors belong to the space generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\... \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\... \end{pmatrix} ... \begin{pmatrix}0\\...\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. Vectors of this type are $2^{n-1}$ because for every entry you can choose whether to put $1$ or $0$, apart from the last one, that is necessarily $0$. In your example you have $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\ \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\ \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\ \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\ \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This method works, though to be formal it should be combined with induction.

Comment: don't think so.. I proved it for every $n \in \N$ and that's enough